# Why time not converted according to time zone?

Tags: java, spring

I have LocalDateTime that keeps value in UTC.
I want to convert it to local date and time  according to a time zone,

here how I do it:

```
public LocalDateTime convertUTC2LocalDateTimeZone(LocalDateTime dateTime){

    System.out.println("dateTime:" + dateTime);
    
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Canada/Mountain"));        
    System.out.println("zonedDateTime:" + zonedDateTime);
    
    LocalDateTime ldt = zonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime()     
    System.out.println("ldt:" + ldt);
    
    return ldt;
}
```

Output:

```
dateTime:2018-07-15T10:00:46
zonedDateTime:2018-07-15T10:00:46-06:00[Canada/Mountain]
ldt:2018-07-15T10:00:46
```

As you can see the ldt value is the same as input, no time conversion occurred.
Any idea why time conversion not occurred?

Comment: Actually, this smells like a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Most of these kinds of shenanigans can be avoided/simplified by picking the correct data type for the correct task (for example just using `Instant` to represent a single point in time and only convert it to a `ZoneDateTime` on the UI layer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `LocalDateTime` represents a "local time and date". In other words: it's something abstract like "January 1st 2020, 10:00 AM" without any time zone information.

It does **not** represent anything in UTC. There simply **is no** time zone information contained in it.

So it doesn't represent a "physical" or exact point in time. To do this you need to convert it to a `ZonedDateTime` by adding some time zone. The way you do in your code basically says: "Give me a `ZonedDateTime` object that represents the local time provided by this `LocalDateTime` in the given time zone".

That means this `ZonedDateTime` **does** represent a fixed point in time (i.e. you can calculate the milliseconds since the epoch, basically).

Then you ask "given that `ZonedDateTime`, what would the local date/time be?", which will just return the value that you initially put in without any modification.

To actually convert from UTC to some other timezone, you need to *explicitly* create a `ZonedDateTime` in the UTC timezone first:

1. create `ZonedDateTime` representing UTC
2. calculate `ZonedDateTime` in the target timezone
3. get a `LocalDateTime` from the `ZonedDateTime` created in #2.

So in code:

```
ZonedDateTime utcDateTime = dateTime.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);   // #1
ZonedDateTime mountainDateTime = utcDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Canada/Mountain"));   // #2
LocalDateTime localDateTimeAtMountain = mountainDateTime.toLocalDateTime();  // #3
```